# Windows 10 - The LoadUserProfile call failed with the following error: Element not found

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

I noticed that my SQL Server service was not running. I tried restarting the service, but it failed.

I went the the Event Manager and discovered that the **LoadUserPofile** call was failing with the following error: `Element not found`, and with event ID 7005.

Though my subsequent research, I discovered that this failure does affect a few services including the SQL Server service.

However, I have absolutely no issues logging into Window via my user account. There are no errors displayed. I would never have even known about this error had my C# program not failed to connect to the database, which caused me to investigate the SQL Service, which caused me to explore the Event Manager.

Up to a few days ago, my C# program was easily connecting to its SQL Server database without any issues, so this event error is recent. I do not know/remember if any Windows updates occurred during the interim. I did not install any programs whatsoever during the past week.

---

I have tried some of the recommended solutions.

In RegEdit, in the following registry key: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

I found the entry for my profile and verified that `State` = 0. I did not have an entry for `RefCount`, but created one with its default value of 0. I rebooted, but the same error is logged in the Event Viewer.

Neither the `NTUSER.dat` file not the `USERCLASS.dat` files were read-only, and my user retains full control over both files.

I booted into Safe Mode and ran `sfc /scannow`. No errors were found via that command.

There is an offered solution to create a new profile, but I am not sure how this will affect my experience as a user. Will I lose my Start menu configurations? My desktop configurations?

**Question:** Has anyone else experienced this exact same error event and were able to resolve it?

```
The LoadUserProfile call failed with the following error: Element not found.
```

Comment: Under which account is the SQL Server service running ?

Comment: It's running under "NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: Can you manage to use [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038479/where-are-my-local-sql-server-express-database-files) to locate your database files?

Comment: My database files are not actually missing. The SQL Server service issue is a symptom of the failure of the LoadUserProfile call.

Comment: Try perhaps to trace the execution using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), to find why the message "Element not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Open REGEDIT and navigate to the following key:
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

You should see some keys with a `.bak` extension and that have subkeys named `ProfileImagePath` that end with "`SQLEXPRESS`". Swap them with their matching keys that do not have the extension. (In my case, I had two such keys.

In the swapped keys without the `*.bak` extension, make sure that the `State` subkey is set to `0`.

Reboot the computer and you the SQL Server service should start automatically.

[image]